# Disable setting of a property in winforms designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, designer

I'm using [Yet Another TabControl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12538/Y-et-A-nother-TabControl-A-Custom-Tab-Control-With) in my project - it's custom, open sourced TabControl with support for designer. After solving some of its problems, I've stumbled upon a problem I have no clue how to solve.

When I run my application, YATabControl would select the same tab I selected in designer - which is not exactly what I want (I'd rather start with first tab) and I can't move through the tabs while application is running, because it tries to save property "SelectedIndex" on every change of tab.

It is set on designers ~onclick using:

```
RaiseComponentChanging( TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( Control )[ "SelectedIndex" ] );  
RaiseComponentChanged( TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( Control )[ "SelectedIndex" ], oi, i );(old index, index).
```

I'm thinking - is there a way to disable designer from setting runtime value of property?

Comment: Not a fix, but as a workaround couldn't you just chance the selected index in the constructor?

Comment: And you can check DesignMode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.COMPONENTMODEL.COMPONENT.DESIGNMODE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

Comment: Where in the constructor are you setting it? Ensure you set it after InitialiseComponents(); What about in the Load event?

Comment: It sounds like the value of SelectedIndex is getting serialized.  Drop the control on a form and look at the form's Designer.cs file.  Make sure that the SelectedIndex property is not being set.

Comment: @Ryan: It works well, when I set the selected index in constructor of Form, where those tabcontrols reside. It always shows the first tab where I need it. Still - it changes my designer & resx files every time I look through the tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at the source code (didn't download it), but it looks like you have to tell the `SelectedIndex` property to not serialize itself:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public virtual int SelectedIndex {
  get {
    return yaSelectedIndex;
  }
  set {...}
}
```

Comment: The only thing that this answer lacks: on every RaiseComponentChanged/Changing it rewrites the designer file, so it's good to cut out those which edit only the not applicable properties (those which are not serialized) - that way you won't have to worry about selecting different tabs in the designer while the application is in debug.

Answer (score 3):

`[Browseable(false)]` is the way to go :)

Comment: that's `[Browsable(false)]`: "Specifies whether a property or event should be displayed in a Properties window."

Answer (score 0):

You need both attributes, so like this:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public bool MyExtraProperty { get; set; }
```